# vitest/vue-testing-library - mock error -> What is the recommended approach?

Tags: vitest, vue-testing-library

I've been struggling with some tests for some time and I cannot find a proper way to make them work.

I use vitest, vue-testing-library and jest-dom when useful.

What I want is to be able to use different mocked data for different tests and I cannot find a way to do that. If I use the same stuff in a beforeEach() loop

```
beforeEach(() => {
useQuery1.mockResolvedValue({
      data1: {
        amount: 0,
        date: '2021-01-01',
      },
      data2: { amount: 0 },
      data3: { amount: 0 },
      data4: { amount: 0 },
      data5: {
        total: 0,
        url: 'https://www.google.com',
      },
    })
}
```

it works fine but that's not what I want.

Here's a simplified sample of my test file:

```
vi.mock('@/dashboard/queries/useQuery1')

describe('Widget1', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Reset the mock before each test
    useDivisionWidgetsQuery.mockReset()
  })

  test('test 1', async () => {
    useQuery1.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      data1: {
        amount: 0,
        date: '2021-01-01',
      },
      data2: { amount: 0 },
      data3: { amount: 0 },
      data4: { amount: 0 },
      data5: {
        total: 0,
        url: 'https://www.google.com',
      },
    })

    render(Widget1, {
      props: props,
    })

    const futureTitle = screen.getByText('Future')
    expect(futureTitle).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  test('test 2', async () => {
    useQuery1.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      data1: null, // different data
      data2: { amount: 0 },
      data3: { amount: 0 },
      data4: { amount: 0 },
      data5: {
        total: 0,
        url: 'https://www.google.com',
      },
    })

    render(Widget1, {
      props: props,
    })

    const futureTitle = screen.getByText('Future')
    expect(futureTitle).not.toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Separately the tests work fine but the issue is related to vi.mock() I guess.

> The error message is the following :
>
> This error originated in "assets/tests/vitest/components/Widget1.spec.ts" test file. It doesn't mean the error was thrown inside the file itself, but while it was running.

It seems that there a many, many ways to mock the stuff we want and I already spent hours looking for answers here and nothing has been working so far.

Thanks in adance.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is something like this

```
const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => ({
  useQuery1: vi.fn(),
}));

vi.mock('@/dashboard/queries/useQuery1', () =>({
  useQuery1: mocks.useQuery1,
}));
```

and then in your tests, you could `mocks.useQuery1.mockResolvedValue(...)`

For more information, [check this https://vitest.dev/api/vi#vi-hoisted](https://vitest.dev/api/vi#vi-hoisted)